# while-loop and for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I want to creat an alogrithm in R using while and for such that, given a vector V and an integer M, sums the elements of the vector V until that sum exceeds M, and I want it to inform the value that exceeded M as well as how many repetitions it took in order to exceed such number (i.e., how many elements of the vector did it summed). I was thinking in something like this:

```
V <- 1:10
X <- 14
Sum <- 0
n <- 0

for (i in 1:length(V)){
  while (Sum <= X){
    Sum <- sum(V[1:i])
    n <- n + 1
  }
}
print(Sum)
print(n)
```

But the loop doesn't load. Something's off. Hope the problem it's clear. Thanks!

Comment: add print(paste0("Sum: ", Sum)) the next line after your "while" and you should be able to figure it out. also 2 people have taken their time to answer your problem in other thread. would be polite to accept an answer.

Comment: Hmm, it's not working. I just get a lot of "Sum: 3". Why do you think that would solve the problem?
And I'll accept the answer in the other thread now. Thanks!

Comment: It does not solve the problem. It offers you the opportunity to understand the problem. "while" contains a condition. The loop will run as long as Sum <= X. so Sum should grow at each iteration of your while loop until it becomes bigger than X. The print shows you the value of Sum. Do you see "Sum" growing? Where is Sum supposed to change?

Comment: Ha! I see. I changed "Sum <- sum(V[1:i])" to "Sum <- Sum + V[i]", but something doesn't work still. Evidently I can't put in in code, but I want the following. Take Sum = 0 and i = 1. If it is less than 14, add 1 to Sum. Then if Sum is still less than 14, take i=2 and add 2 to Sum. And so forth until Sum > 14.

Comment: That's a start. Your problem is you don't understand what is a loop. You do not need a nested loop (ie a loop in a loop, in this case a while in a for). A single loop will do. Your example is close to the fun_while or the fun_for of Rui or of my f.loop in your original question. You haven't understood the code we gave you then you're stuck.

Comment: I posted an answer but really I advise you not to read it until you understand your issue. But it's up to you...

Comment: You're misreading me. I'm giving you the best advice I got when I was in your position. I'm telling you it's better *for you* to understand what is a for loop rather than getting an answer on how to fix an error in your first attempt. good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247575/discussion-between-gaspar-and-will).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
V <- 1:10
X <- 14
Sum <- 0
n <- 0

# For each i between 1 and 10
for (i in 1:length(V)){
    # Sum is equal to the sum of the i first terms
    Sum <- sum(V[1:i])
    # I increment n by 1
    n <- n + 1
    # if Sum is greater than X I get out of the for loop
    if (Sum > X) {
      break
    }
}
print(Sum)
print(n)

V <- 1:10
X <- 14
Sum <- 0
n <- 1

# as long as Sum is smaller or equal than X
while (Sum <= X){
  # Sum is the sum of the first n terms of V
  Sum <- sum(V[1:n])
  # I increment n by 1
  n <- n + 1
}

print(Sum)
print(n-1)
```